# Acquiring Row index with identity column in Join Query

Tags: sql-server

I need to add the results from a Left Join query to a table that does not have its index set to be an identity, but the int must still be unique. My insert query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (S.SubjectID, S.Subject, S.SubjectDescription, S.Status)
SELECT (Select MAX(SubjectID) FROM Table1) + ???? , N.Code, N.Literal, N.Trans
FROM  Table2 N LEFT JOIN Table1 S ON N.Code = S.Subject   
WHERE (N.Code IS NULL OR S.Subject IS NULL OR N.Trans = 'D')
```

Where I have the ???? is where i need to have some incrementing value so that when inserting into the table1 the ID's will be unique.

I am not allowed to change the table's structure, I just need something that can calculate his on the fly.

As always help, tips and references are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases, you can use `row_number()` for this purpose.  Here is an example with SQL Server syntax:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (S.SubjectID, S.Subject, S.SubjectDescription, S.Status)
SELECT (Select MAX(SubjectID) FROM Table1) + row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) ,
       N.Code, N.Literal, N.Trans
FROM  Table2 N LEFT JOIN Table1 S ON N.Code = S.Subject   
WHERE (N.Code IS NULL OR S.Subject IS NULL OR N.Trans = 'D')
```

Comment: Ah Thank you, that row_number() was exactly what I was looking for. I didn't see it on the W3S website which is why I posted here.